# Attempt of fit a Gaussian distribution: Error scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 765, in curve_fit raise ValueError("`sigma` has incorrect shape.")

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian, standard-deviation

I have a pretty known issue but impossible to fix for the moment.
This is about `curve_fit` function. I get the error:

> Error scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 765, in curve_fit raise ValueError("`sigma` has incorrect shape.")

Here is the code, don't make caution to the loop for, it is just I would like 5 different histograms:

```
for i in range(5):
  mean_o[i] = np.mean(y3[:,i])
  sigma_o[i] = np.std(y3[:,i])

## Histograms
# Number of bins
Nbins=100
binwidth = np.zeros(5)

# Fitting curves
def gaussian(x, a, mean, sigma):
  return a * np.exp(-((x - mean)**2 / (2 * sigma**2)))

for i in range(5):

  binwidth[i] = (max(y3[:,i]) - min(y3[:,i]))/Nbins
  bins_plot = np.arange(min(y3[:,i]), max(y3[:,i]) + binwidth[i], binwidth[i])
  plt.title('Distribution of O observable for redshift bin = '+str(z_ph_fid[i]))
  plt.hist(y3[:,i], bins=bins_plot, label='bin '+str(z_ph_fid[i]))
  plt.legend(loc='upper right')
  # Fitting and plot
  range_fit = np.linspace(min(y3[:,i]), max(y3[:,i]), len(y3[:,i]))
  popt, pcov = curve_fit(gaussian, range_fit, y3[:,i], mean_o[i], sigma_o[i])
  plt.plot(range_fit, gaussian(range_fit, *popt))
  # Save figure
  plt.savefig('chi2_gaussian_bin_'+str(i+1)+'.png')
  plt.close()
```

The first histogram `i=0` look like:

[image: Hisotgram]

I would like to plot a red Gaussian fit over the histogram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with the OP.

First problem is that the code tries to fit the random samples with a normal distribution. This is wrong. One can fit the output of the histogram, though. This is shown in the code below. Better would be the use of `scipy.stats.norm.fit()` which allows to fit the random samples. This is also shown.

Second problem is the sigma-shape. Here `curve_fit` is actually expecting errors on the y-data, which naturally needs the shape of the y-data. What should have been done is: providing start values for the fit. This is shown below as well.

Code looks like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

mean_o = list()
sigma_o = list()
y3 = list()

### generate some data
for i in range( 5 ):
    y3.append( norm.rvs( size=150000 ) )
y3 = np.transpose( y3 )

for i in range(5):
    mean_o.append( np.mean( y3[ :, i ] ) )
    sigma_o.append(  np.std( y3[ :, i ] ) )

## Histograms
# Number of bins
Nbins=100
binwidth = np.zeros(5)

# Fitting curves
def gaussian( x, a , mean, sigma ):
  return a * np.exp( -( ( x - mean )**2 / (2 * sigma**2 ) ) )

fig = plt.figure()
ax = { i : fig.add_subplot( 2, 3, i+1) for i in range( 5 ) }


for i in range(5):
    ymin = min(y3[:,i])
    ymax = max(y3[:,i])
    binwidth[i] = ( ymax - ymin) / Nbins
    bins_plot = np.arange( ymin, ymax + binwidth[i], binwidth[i])
    histdata = ax[i].hist(
        y3[:,i],
        bins=bins_plot,
        label='bin '+str(i)
    )

    range_fit = np.linspace( ymin, ymax, 250)
    # Fitting and plot version 1
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(
        gaussian,
        0.5 * ( histdata[1][:-1] + histdata[1][1:] ),
        histdata[0],
        p0=( max(histdata[0]), mean_o[i], sigma_o[i] ) )
    ax[i].plot(range_fit, gaussian( range_fit, *popt ) )
    ax[i].axvline( x=mean_o[i], ls=':', c='r' )

    # Fitting and plot version 2
    params = norm.fit( y3[ ::, i ], loc=mean_o[i], scale=sigma_o[i] )
    nth = gaussian(
        range_fit,
        len( y3[::, i]) * binwidth[i] / np.sqrt( 2 * np.pi ),
        *params
    )
    ax[i].plot(range_fit, nth, ls="--" )
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works ! just a detail, how to put the best fit value on `ax[i]` axis ? I mean, how to add `mean_o[i]` on x axis of each plot ? Best regards

Comment: @stefan I'll make an update....also forgot to mention an important point.

Comment: Thanks, I don't see the modifications  for the red vertical line (best fit), this is what you say ? you will make an update ? Regards

Comment: @stefan ... sorry. added: `ax[i].axvline( x=mean_o[i], ls=':', c='r' )`